# Python pandas: appending information from a dictionary to rows while looping through dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, append

I would like to know a better way to append information to a dataframe while in a loop, specifically, to add COLUMNS of information to a dataframe from a dictionary. The code below technically works, but in subsequent analyses I would like to preserve the data classifications of numpy/pandas to be able to efficiently classify missing data or odd values as np.nan or null. Any tips would be great.

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['John', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
'age': [42, 17, 16, 24, '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])
headers = df.columns.values
count = 0
adults = {'John':True,'Molly':False}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count += 1
    if str(row['first_name']) in adults:
        adult = adults[str(row['first_name'])]
    else:
        adult = 'null'
    headers = np.append(headers,'ADULT')
    vals = np.append(row.values,adult)
    if count == 1:
        print ','.join(headers.tolist())
        print str(vals.tolist()).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
    else:
        print str(vals.tolist()).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'","")
```

Output:

```
first_name,last_name,age,ADULT
John, Miller, 42, True
Molly, Jacobson, 20, True
Tina, Ali, 16, NA
Jake, Milner, 24, NA
Amy, Cooze, , NA
```

Comment: You could use map and map values ages above to True and ages below FALSE. Not in front of computer rn otherwise I'd give you tested answer but I want to say something like df.ADULT.map(df.Age>18:true;df.Age<18:False) would work or maybe you need a lambda function (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `loop`, I think you can simply use `lambda` with `if` and `else` condition:

```
df['ADULT'] = df['first_name'].apply(lambda v: adults[v] if v in adults else np.nan)
print(df.to_csv(index=False, na_rep='NA'))

# Output is:

# first_name,last_name,age,ADULT
# John,Miller,42,True
# Molly,Jacobson,17,False
# Tina,Ali,16,NA
# Jake,Milner,24,NA
# Amy,Cooze,,NA
```

In above, `adults[val] if val in adults else np.nan` simply looks for if `val` i.e. `first_name` for each row is in dictionary, if it is then value is kept for new column else `np.nan`

You can use `to_csv` to print in above format, here without specifying filename, it converts to string with comma separated and `na_rep` specifies string to use for missing values.